# how to remove border of a hyper-link image?

Tags: html, hyperlink

```
<li><a href="#" ><img src="images/hospitality.png" title="" /></a>
```

**Problem- image is getting displayed inside a blue rectangle box in IE and Mozilla but not in Chrome.How can I remove that blue box from IE also?**

Comment: The answer that didn't include the CSS inline is a better one. You ought to have accepted it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Or add it inline to the img element:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img style="border: 0;" src="images/hospitality.png" title="" />
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Why would you encourage someone to write an inline style?

Comment: @Rowan when making a HTML email?

Answer (score 48):

You can set this CSS to remove the blue border on every image within a link:

```
a img {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The "border=0" solution works, but it is not very easy to implement since it requires its addition in every and each link image you put in your project.

The better solution is to include the following tag within your page's `<head>`...`</head>` tags, which can be in a master page so that all the inner pages will inherent it from the master page

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!--
    img { border: none; }
    -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

external css

```
img {border : 0;}
img a {outline : none;}
```

internal css

```
<style type="text/css">
  img { border: none; }
</style>
```

inline css

```
<img src="logo.png" style="border-style: none"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For removing this border you should set border to none.

```
  a img 
        {
        border:none;
        }
```